# Find all Users with conditions of nested association - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find all Users who have replied to a particular post.

Users have many Messages. Messages have one Conversation. I'm using a column on the Conversation table called `related_object_id` to make sure it relates to the right post.

I've tried things like this:

```
1.  User.all.where(:messages.conversation(:related_object_id => post))

2.  User.all.where(messages.select {|m| m.conversation.where(:related_object_id => post)})
```

Pretty bad attempts (I know I can't access the `messages` association through `where` like that) but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
User.joins(messages: :conversation).where(conversations: { related_object_id: post }).uniq
```